# XeLaTeX and pst-node

Tags: xetex, pstricks, pst-node

I have problems with XeLaTeX and pst-node:
If I want to draw a line between two nodes, but there is nothing drawn in the pspicture. If I only put the nodes with some stuff withoud a line in, the nodes are drawn, but the line is missing.

The way LaTeX -> DVI -> PS -> PDF works, but not direct to pdf with XeLaTeX. Can anyone help me here?

MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}

\fbox{
    \begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(2,2)
    \rput(1,0){\rnode{A}{Stuff A}}
    \rput(0,1){\rnode{B}{Stuff b}}
    \ncline{A}{B}
\end{pspicture}
}

\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(2,2)
    \rput(1,0){\rnode{A}{Stuff A}}
    \rput(0,1){\rnode{B}{Stuff b}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Edit: Added \listfile:

```
   *File List*
  scrartcl.cls    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script document class (article)
  scrkbase.sty    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent bas
  ics and keyval usage)
   scrbase.sty    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent b
  asics and keyval usage)
    keyval.sty    2014/05/08 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
  scrlfile.sty    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
  tocbasic.sty    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
  scrsize11pt.clo    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt)
  typearea.sty    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (type area)
  pstricks.sty    2013/12/12 v0.60 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
     ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
  pstricks.tex    2014/08/27 v2.57 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
  pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
   xkeyval.sty    2014/05/25 v2.7 package option processing (HA)
   xkeyval.tex    2014/05/25 v2.7 key=value parser (HA)
    pst-fp.tex    2014/08/27 v2.57 `PST-fp' (hv)
    xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
     color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
     xetex.def    2014/07/25 v4.03 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (RRM/JK)

  pst-node.sty    2010/04/22 package wrapper for pst-node.tex
  pst-node.tex    2014/08/04 1.35 `pst-node' (tvz,hv)
   ***********
```

I use texlive 2014 with:

```
 This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99991 (TeX Live 2014/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 \write18 enabled.
```

Comment: I have no such problem. Which system/version of xelatex/version of pst-node do you have?

Comment: The xdvi driver of XeTeX has some problems with nodes. I'll have a look at it.

Comment: @Herbert: XeLaTeX even won't draw a line or a frame, is this related to the problem you mentioned? And do you know how long it  will take to solve it?

Comment: The problem is the node dictionary and it is not easy to find the problem inside of the `xdvipdfmx` program. I cannot say how long it may take. Use `auto-pst-pdf` and `pdflatex` until it will be fixed.

Comment: @Herbert: Do you have an explanation about me being able to compile with XeLaTeX? I'm under MiKTeX 2.9, Windows 7 Pro.

Comment: Works for me (TL 2014/MacTeX) [picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/13CH8.png)

Comment: @Bernard: With current TL2014 and Windows 8.1 I'll get the same problem. Which Ghostscript version do you have?

Comment: Is there any way to change auto-pst-pdf or a command to make pdfcrop use \jobname.pdf as output? I have only one picture in the file and use this in my thesis.

Comment: @Herbert: I have MiKTeX 2.9, and I have an independent Ghostscript installation, Ghostscript X64 9.15 (never had problems with previous versions of GhostScript since I use XeLaTeX). Don't know if XeLaTeX uses MiKteX's version or mine, though.

Comment: @Bernard: Ah, I see. Then I suppose a problem with the ghostscript version. I'll test some other versions

Comment: @Niklas: You can use `\usepackage[pspdf={-o myname.pdf}]{auto-pst-pdf}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is GhostScript. With the version 9.10 it works, with the current version 9.15 it doesn't work. Also with some other GS versions.

I installed GhostScript from the source into `/usr/local/src`:

```
wget http://downloads.ghostscript.com/public/ghostscript-9.10.tar.gz
tar -xvzf ghostscript-9.10.tar.gz 
cd ghostscript-9.10
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

However, there should be ready made binaries in the net for all platforms.
The output with 9.10:

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you. Do you know how to do this on Windows 7 with texlive 2014?

Comment: Here are exe files for windows: http://www.ghostscript.com/GPL_Ghostscript_9.10.html

Comment: @Herbert: I installed gs9.10 and changed the path in my editor, but still no correct results.

Answer (score 1):

Now I solved my problem with your help:

I installed GS9.10, then copyed the files in from `C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.10\bin` to `C:\texlive\2014\tlpkg\tlgs\bin`. Thats all I needed, now the results are correct.

Thank you all for the help!