# Xelatex has problem in generating pstricks tex file with colors

Tags: xetex, color, pstricks, linux, ghostscript

I have a piece of simple tex code which compiles on all of my computers. But it doesn't show properly on my laptop

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\psset{gridcolor=green, subgridcolor=yellow}
\begin{document}   
\psset{unit=1cm}
\centering
\begin{pspicture}(-7.5,5.2)(7.5,8.4)
  \psgrid
  \rput[B](0,8){
    \psframebox[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=gray!20]{
      \Rnode{A0}{$a_0$}
      \Rnode{A1}{$\cdots$}
      \Rnode{A2}{\color{red} $a_{t-2m-1}$}
      \Rnode{A3}{$\cdots$}
      \Rnode{A4}{$a_{t-m-1}$}
    }
  }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Here I show the problematic result:

[image: This is how the result looks like]

It should have a frame box around the content in gray color. Also, it should have shown the grid. I am using Texlive 2014, the most updated version. I compared the log files for the correct result and wrong result, which are exactly the same. No error reported. However, I don't know what is wrong.

Using latex and then dvipdf could get the right file.

I have delete the texlive and reinstalled. Nothing changed. It seems that something related to the operating system is affecting. Please help. Thanks.

I am using Arch linux.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I have no problem with your code. I see a gridded box with the mathematical text

Comment: Do you have any particular reason to suspect the operating system? The MWE works perfectly for me on Debian GNU/Linux with a vanilla TeX Live 2014. Are you using a different PDF viewer on your laptop?

Comment: @Thérèse I have checked on another Arch linux platform, it shows the same problem. As far as I know, it works with Ubuntu. I suspect that it has something to do with certain system components, because it was working a few days ago before one upgrade.

Comment: The problem occurs when compiling with XeLaTeX, not via a LaTeX > dvips > ps2pdf compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking the recently updated packages, I found ghostscript was updated from 9.14-1 to 9.15-1, which is very suspicious as I could find any problem exists in Texlive 2014 itself.
After downgrading, this problem is solved. I am not sure what is wrong with this new ghostscript.

Xelatex must called some postscript functionalities from ghostscript.

Comment: A similar problem seen in Windows is described here [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204269/xelatex-and-pst-node)

Comment: Under Windows I'm running Ghostscript 9.14 and the problem still exists. With your current answer relating to Ghostscript being the culprit, this question seems to be a duplicate.

Comment: @antiquity: it is a problem with ghostscript _and_ xdvipdfmx. Downgrading to ghostscript 9.10 should help for Linux and Windows. The next TL version will have an updated xdvipdfmx.