# PSTricks drawing not cropped in standalone

Tags: pstricks, standalone, crop, pst-optexp

I'm trying to create a drawing using the `pst-optexp` package, and I can get the drawing to compile, but the output is not cropped to the drawing (the drawing is just placed in the top left corner of a full-sized page). Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-optexp}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-1)(1,1)
\pnode(0,0){oap}
\pnode(-3,0){enter}
\pnode(0,-1){focus}

\oapmirror[labelangle=160,labeloffset=1.5](enter)(oap)(focus){collimating}

\multido{\r=-0.4+0.1}{9}{
    \drawbeam[beampos=\r,ArrowInside=-<,linewidth=0.3\pslinewidth](enter){}(focus)
}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Right now I'm compiling using latex->dvips->ps2pdf. I tried using xelatex, which crops correctly but then only the text "collimating" appears in the drawing (I believe it's the same issue in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204269/xelatex-and-pst-node), but I'm using Ghostscript 9.19 on OS X). I tried using pdflatex with shell-escape enabled, and I tried using `auto-pst-pdf`, but nothing has worked so far.

Edit: I completely reinstalled my MacTeX distribution, and that seems to have fixed the problem. I was using the smaller BasicTex distribution before, and had installed any packages that it said that I required, so I'm still not sure what the problem was.

Comment: Did you load `auto-pst-pdf` *after* pst-optexp? For me, it compiles fine with `pdflatex` (Windows 7, MiKTeX  64 bit).

Comment: When I do that, I don't get output at all. I looked at the log and found this:
    Package auto-pst-pdf Warning: 
        Creation of oap_collimating-pics.pdf failed.
        This warning occured on input line 124.
    Package auto-pst-pdf Warning: 
        Could not create oap_collimating-pics.pdf. Auxiliary files not deleted.
        This warning occured on input line 124.
    Package pst-pdf Warning: pspicture No. 1 undefined.

Comment: I really don't know what to say. Is your installation up-to-date? And did you compile just this code (completed with auto-pst-pdf)? Last suggestion: what if you compile with the `article`class (thus, non-cropped, of course)?

Comment: My installation is up to date. When I compile with `article` I get the drawing somewhere on the page, but it's still part of a full-sized page.

Comment: I don't understand, and I can't really help as I have a different system. As a last resource, you can use `pst-eps` to  obtain an `.eps` file (via `latex+dvips -E`), and a tool like `epspdf` (a script written in texlua) will crop it correctly.

Comment: Have you tried `\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}`?

Comment: `pst-optexp` does not work with `xelatex`! You have to use package `auto-pst-pdf` with `pdflatex` or `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`

Comment: @Christoph when I do that I get a properly cropped page, but the page is blank (there is no drawing). This was done with latex->dvips->ps2pdf

Comment: @ZachMitchell: In general on any cropping problem with `standalone` always try it with added `preview` option first. That's the alternative cropping implementation.